# JavaFX - displaying alert or dialog after javascript code completes (GMapsFX, WebView)

Tags: javascript, java, google-maps, javafx, webview

In my JavaFX application I'm using GMapsFX to do route finding and visualizations. For the visualization, I simply use a timeout in Javascript and display markers on the map with delay. What I'm having trouble doing is displaying a dialog (or js alert) after the visualization ends telling information about the search (number of nodes visited, I have this available in both my java and js code). Is there a simple way to do this?

GMapsFX package :
http://rterp.github.io/GMapsFX/

```
public void startVisualization() {

        LatLongBounds bounds = new LatLongBounds();
        List<LatLong> latLongs = new ArrayList<LatLong>();
        JavascriptArray jsArray = new JavascriptArray();
        manager.hideIntermediateMarkers();
        manager.hideDestinationMarker();

        // create Markers
        for(geography.GeographicPoint point : points) {
            LatLong ll = new LatLong(point.getX(), point.getY());
            MarkerOptions options = MarkerManager.createDefaultOptions(ll);
            Marker newMarker = new Marker(options);
            jsArray.push(newMarker);
            markerList.add(newMarker);
            bounds.extend(ll);
        }

        // fit map bounds to visualization
        manager.getMap().fitBounds(bounds);

        // get javascript runtime and execute animation
        runtime = JavascriptRuntime.getInstance();
        String command = runtime.getFunction("visualizeSearch", manager.getMap(), jsArray);
        System.out.println(command);

        runtime.execute(command);

//      MapApp.showInfoAlert("Nodes visited :"  , latLongs.size() +" nodes were visited in the search");
        manager.disableVisButton(true);
//        manager.disableRouteButtons(false);
}
```

```
var delay = 300;
var map, markers;
var markerURL = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/red-diamond-lv.png";
var destURL = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal2/icon5.png";

function visualizeSearch(mapParam, markersParam) {
    markers = markersParam;
    map = mapParam; 
    drop();
}

function displayMarker(marker, timeout, URL) {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        marker.setIcon(URL);
        marker.setMap(map);
    }, timeout);
}

function drop() {
    var i;
    for(i = 1; i < markers.length - 1; ++i) {
        displayMarker(markers[i], i*delay, markerURL);
    }
    displayMarker(markers[markers.length - 1], i*delay, destURL)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The WebView doesn't have a built in alert. Any alert displayed as a result of javascript in the WebView needs to happen by using Alerts/Dialogs or custom views in JavaFX by way of the onAlert event handler. You can get the WebEngine and register an event handler to respond to alert events from the javascript using:

```
gmapview.getWebView().getEngine().setOnAlert(EventHandler<WebEvent<String>> e);
```

Your event handler will get the String value of any javascript alert emitted. From there it's up to you to decide how to display it.